# ksoap2 complex parameter

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I need to call a web service using ksoap2, I have been doign this successfully up till the point where I need to pass a more complex type to the web service.

Does anybody have an example of passing a complex type to a webservice, preferably, only using SoapObject (the object in question is only Strings and dateTimes.

Thanks
in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it. Simply used a SoapObject as a property.

Comment: I am facing the same problem as you did. Can you please give me an idea how you used a SoapObject to send the request ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [android web service client](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/) open source tool.
Where you needn't use the soap Object or think with the soap envelop its just like call a method of a service.

say, for a service say ComplexReqService with param ComplexRequest you have to just write :

```
 ComplexReqService service = new ComplexReqService();
 CoplextReqPort port = service.getPort();
 String resp = port.getResponse ( new ComplexRequest() );
```

In this way, It will support the complex response as well.